# Feature importance for each modality

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am doing a random forest with sklearn in Python.
I try to get the score of each modality for an attribute.
For example, in the titanic dataset, how can we get the score of each modality of the Pclass variable?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pclass variable is a *categorical* variable. This means that it takes on 2 or more discrete values. For such variables, it is always recommended to represent them using [One-Hot](https://www.quora.com/What-is-one-hot-encoding-and-when-is-it-used-in-data-science) encoding. For example if your PClass variable takes 3 possible values, *lower*, *middle* and *upper*, then currently you would be encoding them as 0, 1 or 2. The problem with this approach is that in some classifiers this approach will introduce a natural ordering that *upper* > *lower*. Thus the most commonly used strategy is to encode them as 3 boolean features. So instead of 1 feature, now you will have 3 features. *Lower* will be represented as [1 0 0], *middle* as [0 1 0] and *upper* as [0 0 1].

Since you are using scikit-learn, this can be done by the [`OneHotEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) class. The example in the scikit-learn documentation has an illustrative example.

Now, when you pass these as the features to your random forest and train it. You can easily get the feature importance using `clf.feature_importances_`. Since now, you use one feature for each modality, you can easily get the importance for each feature modality.

Hope that helps.